# Properly Testing an Observable for Simple Component

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, rxjs

I am currently testing a simple component that I have created that looks like this:

```
@Input()
public type: string;

private saveSubscription: Subscription;

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.saveSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onSave();
}

private onSave(): void {
    this.saveSubscription = this.editService.saveSelection.subscribe(() => {
        this.editService.type.next(this.type);
    });
}
```

In my test, I want to make sure that if I set the input manually, and then call `ngOnInit()`, the value emitted by the `editService` will equal my value.

```
it('should set up the subscription for saving', fakeAsync(() => {
    // Arrange
    component.type = 'full';

    // Act
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    mockedEditService.saveSelection.next();

    // Assert
    mockedEditService.type.subscribe(type => {
        expect(type).toEqual(component.type);
    });
}));
```

I'm struggling with testing async code and am not sure if I am doing this correctly. The test always passes even with incorrect test cases and I suspect that the code in question is not waiting for the subscription to resolve before making its assertion.

Reading the Angular [test docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service), I've been able to familiarize myself a bit more, but I was wondering if you all had any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: What is the definition of `saveSelection` method of `mockedEditService` class?

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani `public saveSelection: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();`

Comment: and `expect(type).toEqual(component.type);` will always be success as both values will be same.

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani If I instead change it to something like: `expect(type).toEqual('notCorrect');`, it still passes

Comment: So `expect(type).toEqual(component.type);` isnt being executed.

Answer (score 2):

In the `spec`, have the `subscription` before the `mockedEditService.saveSelection.next`

```
it('should set up the subscription for saving', fakeAsync(() => {
    // Arrange
    component.type = 'full';

    // START ********* MOVE THIS BLOCK UP
    mockedEditService.type.subscribe(type => {
        expect(type).toEqual(component.type);
    });
    // END ********* MOVE THIS BLOCK UP

    // Act
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    mockedEditService.saveSelection.next();


}));
```

Comment: This worked! @BasavarajBhusani could you explain why?

Comment: @User5842, That is because, you have to subscribe to `Observable` or `Subject` before it emits the value. After the emit (or after `.next`) if you `subscribe`, you will not get the value, as new `subscription` listens to the future emitting values not the past emitted values. 


In different cases, You can use `behaviorsubject` or `replaysubject` which store previous value/s. But its not so valid here.